# SQL Error: -302, SQLState: 22001 while using String function with a dynamic parameter in db2/hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

Trying to run a query, in java. Will provide the part where I am facing issue with

`select j.* .......... where lower(jp.value) = lower (:mailTo)...`

`query.setString("mailTo", mailTo);`

`List<Job> listJob = query.list();`

Basically here when the String size is greater it is throwing the below error:
The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=3.69.24

When I am removing the lower function from the binded paramter, it is working fine eg:
`select j.* .......... where lower(jp.value) = (:mailTo)...`

Also the issue is specific to db2, when I am running the same in Oracle/Postgres it is working as expected.

Tried to manually run and it is working as well, but trying to figure out why the issue is happening in hibernate/jdbc.

Comment: Try `lower (cast(:mailTo as VARCHAR(X)))`, where `X` - max expected length of the parameter value passed.

Comment: Getting error with Varchar, so tried to cast as String, but still same issue:(